# Remove insecure content from the page

Tags: html, security, facebook, gwt, iframe

I want to remove insecure content from site

I added facebook social networking box by using following GWT code in HTMLPanel

```
< iframe width='244'  height='242' class='fb-fan-box' src='https://www.facebook.com/connect/connect.php?id="+ FacebookConstants.FB_DUBLIN_PAGE_ID+ "&connections=10&stream=0&css=https://www.supergroupers.com/facebook.css' frameBorder='0' scrolling='no' allowTransparency='allowtransparency'>
```

but when i run above code in browser it internally adds following css file which is insecure

```
< LINK rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="http://external.ak.fbcdn.net/fbml_static_get.php?src=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.supergroupers.com%2Ffacebook.css&amp;appid=106562422725875&amp;pv=1&amp;sig=52d2643d471dad5f75d528ba4ea74dcb&amp;filetype=css">
```

Is there any why to change that http to https

Thanks

but

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should realize that adding content from any other external domain is in itself a security and privacy issue. If you are building a website that warrants https, you should NOT be including content from facebook.

Second, the issue you describe is a problem with facebook. They should be using protocol relative urls, and they are not. Nothing you can do to fix it, unless facebook provides a https version of their site that has a different url.